# Combobox add range alternative

Tags: c#

I basically want to add ages from 1 to 100, but I don't want to type each one in the string[], something like add 1 then increment until 100

I have this at the moment

```
cmbAge.Items.AddRange(new string[] {"1", "2","3","4",...});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either a `for` loop, as was suggested, or `Enumerable.Range` (which returns an `int`):

```
cmbAge.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100));
```

If you want an `IEnumerable<string>` you have to `Select`:

```
cmbAge.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
    cmbAge.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Does not want to compile, object reference not set

Comment: That's a runtime error, not a compilation error and it means you're doing something wrong somewhere else (not initializing something) as there is nothing in my answer that could cause that error. Debug and figure out what's null.